# Cannot get the counts of a job in Qiskit with the usual command

Tags: qiskit, programming

When I use `job.result().get_counts` I am getting this result:

```
<bound method Result.get_counts of <qiskit.result.result.Result object at ...>>
```

but no counts at all. I have tested it both with a new job and with an old one and in both cases the counts are not shown.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `()` at the end of `job.result().get_counts()`.

Comment: Thanks, then the command changed. Do you know where can I find updates on the code?

Comment: The command has not changed.  It has been there as far back as the GitHub repo lets one search:

https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/12812ed84cdea1e5c110b1f38cc68b2b13c570c8/qiskit/result/result.py#L123

Comment: If you want to see what changes in each Qiskit release, look here: https://qiskit.org/documentation/release_notes.html

Answer (score 1):

Always in Python you need to put brakcets whenever you call a function:

```
job.result().get_counts(<function parameters>)
```

The parameter is a circuit name or index. If you run a single circuit then it should be:

```
job.result().get_counts()
```